# What is the unique identifier of a tenant in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, multi-tenancy

Consider a provider-hosted SharePoint add-in installed in a SharePoint Online tenant. When the add-in is activated and contacts its dedicated server-side website I'd like the add-in to uniquely identify the tenant.

From what I've seen, the only bits of data sent from the tenant to the add-in website are in the query string. And of these, only one - `SPHostUrl` - identifies the calling site collection.

For example:
`?SPHostUrl=https://mytestsite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev`

Would it be correct to use the domain name of the host URL as the unique identifier for the tenant? In the example above: `mytestsite.sharepoint.com`

I would assume a more stable and unique identifier might be available for the SharePoint Online tenant? Possibly a GUID?

Answer (score 1):

The query string variable **SPHostUrl** is your only bet in present implementation of App Model if you are creating a Multi-tenant Provider-hosted application.